# ASP.NET Core 2 Set Basepath for an item located in another application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

This is my program structure:

- App.UI
- App.ClassLibrary

This is the Program.cs located in App.UI. Would it be possible to set the basepath to App.ClassLibrary?

```
public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; } = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(ConfigurationManager.GetBasePath())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json", optional: true)
    .Build();
```

The intention is to use the appsettings.json file located there instead of the main application.

This is what I have done:
In my App.ClassLibrary I have this class

```
public static class ConfigurationManager
{
    public static IConfiguration AppSetting { get; }
    public static string GetBasePath()
    {
        return Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    }

    static ConfigurationManager()
    {
        AppSetting = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location))
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .Build();
    }
}
```

However, when I run the application, I get this exception:

> FileNotFoundException: The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was
>   not found and is not optional. The physical path is
>   'C:\Users\user\Source\Repos\APPStore\App\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\appsettings.json'.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it.
Turns out I needed to set my appsettings on my other app to copy always.